# Android MQTT paho client library does not work with higher API level

Tags: java, android, mqtt, paho

I have been working on Paho Mqtt Client app in Android. The Service for running Mqtt in background works until minimum SDK Version is 8. As I wanted Inbox Style notification in the app, I required to increase the SDK version but while running, it throws runtime exception with Service can not start with MqttClient. Does this have to do with the library file .jar added. can not .jar be compatible with higher API level?

Comment: did you used  compile 'org.eclipse.paho:org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3:1.0.2' ?????

Comment: Please post your logcat

Comment: I am using  org.eclipse.paho:org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3:1.0.1.version.

Comment: 1.0.2 now is supporting higher version too.. Thanks.